# xul dialog box wont have maximize and minimize buttons after updating firefox to version 32.0

Tags: firefox, dialog, xul

used dialog tag in xul for a dialog box for an xul application.Earlier before firefox update the tool had **maximize and minimize buttons** but after update the buttons are **no longer there in the tool**.

Answer (score 0):

MDN Docs: [Window.openDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.openDialog), [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open), <[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/window)>, <[dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/dialog)>, <[dialogheader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/dialogheader)>, [Dialogs and Prompts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Dialogs_and_Prompts)

Without all of: The Firefox version from which you were upgrading, the version you upgraded to, the code you are using to open the window, and the XUL used to describe the window it is difficult to provide you with an answer which actually covers what you want to know.

[MDN has the following to say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) on dialog windows: "Dialog windows are windows which have no minimize system command icon and no maximize/restore down system command icon on the titlebar nor in correspondent menu item in the command system menu. They are said to be dialog because their normal, usual purpose is to only notify info and to be dismissed, closed. On Mac systems, dialog windows have a different window border and they may get turned into a sheet."

That makes is clear that dialog windows do not *normally* have the controls you are asking about.

However, you can pass `minimizable` in the `features` parameter of the `window.open()` or `window.openDialog()` functions to turn on minimize control.

In general, if you want a dialog to have minimize and maximize buttons, you have to open it as a normal window with `window.open()`. You can limit the other toolbars that it has at the top by supplying appropriate parameters in the `window.open()` call. You can also make it modal, like some dialogs. You then create your own *OK* and *Cancel* buttons with appropriate code to accept the information in the dialog or cancel.  Basically, if you want a maximized window for a dialog it should usually be doing quite a bit.  In such case, you probably want more control over how your window looks than is available from a dialog window. Dialogs are, generally, subset of what windows can do with the ability to have a few buttons easily provided.